# Javascript searching for a list in a string

Tags: javascript

I want to know if a string, contains any member of an array. And if it contains,

return that member.

```
    var cat_list = ["apple", "james", "hello", "drink"];
    var title = "James always drinks water"
```

In this case should return both "James" and "drink"

Comment: And where is your attempt to do so ? Basic for loop do this for you.

Comment: Why does "drinks" match "drink"?

Comment: because drinks includes drink!

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the array and check it using `indexOf`.

```
var foundWords = [];
for(var i=0; i<cat_list.length; i++){
    var currentWord = cat_list[i];
    if(title.indexOf(currentWord)>-1){
        foundWords.push(currentWord);
    }
}
```

After the execution of the above `for` statement array `foundWords` would contain the words founds in the title.

Another way to solve the above problem is using the [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method like below:

```
var foundWords = catList.reduce(function(foundWords, currentWord){
    if(title.indexOf(currentWord)>-1){
        foundWords.push(currentWord)
    }
    return foundWords;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a loop in `cat_list` and get the result.

```js
var cat_list = ["apple", "james", "hello", "drink"];
var title = "James always drinks water"

var res = cat_list.filter((item)=>{
    return title.indexOf(item) !== -1;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cat_list = ["apple", "james", "hello", "drink"];
var title = "James always drinks water";
var member = [];
cat_list.map((value)=>{
 title.includes(value) && member.push(value);
});
console.log(member);
```

Comment: Why the `.map()` if you're not going to use its return value?

Comment: with return, it adds the `undefined` element to the array. So, I just removed `return` and `.map()` is okay with looping.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `.map()`. You're "misusing" it as a replacement of `.forEach()` (or `.filter()`)

Answer (score 0):

First problem

Use Array[index]

```
 z= cat_list[1]+cat_list[3];
 alert(z);
```

Second problem

Use   substring() method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

```
 v= title.substring(0,5)+title.substring(13,18);
 alert(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the given string in word parts and then check if the lower case word includes a word from the catalog.

- [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with regular expression for white space characters,
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) where just one found returns a `true` value for `filter`,
- [`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) for getting lower case letters to check against with
- [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for returnung the check for `some` and then for `filter`.

```js
var catalog = ["apple", "james", "hello", "drink"],
    string = "James always drinks water",
    result = string
        .split(/\W+/)
        .filter(word => catalog.some(c => word.toLowerCase().includes(c)));
        
console.log(result);
```